# Change the position of program lead to syntax error

Tags: perl

I have a program called `shuffle.pl` . When I use `perl shuffle.pl Input Shuffled` to execute , it success work and show no error .

I create a directory called `./tools` under my home directory , and I set this path to `.cshrc` . So I can execute the program without typing `perl` to execute . ( This is my first time to do this , maybe some wrong in here)

But when I move the shuffle.pl to ~/.tools and execute . it show I have error in line 5 . But if I use `perl ~/.tools/shuffle.pl`it can work . So it means it should have no syntax error in my program ,But why it can't work after I put my program to ~/.tools

error message

```
.tools/shuffle.pl: 5: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

.cshrc

```
set path = (. ~ ~/.tools /sbin /bin /usr/sbin /usr/bin /usr/games /usr/local/sbin /usr/local/bin )
```

[image]

thanks

here is my program

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util qw(first max maxstr min minstr reduce shuffle sum); 

open(my $fh,"<","$ARGV[0]");
my @Lines = readline($fh);
my @Shuffled = shuffle(@Lines);
close $fh;

open(my $shuf,">","$ARGV[1]");
print $shuf @Shuffled;
close $shuf;
```

[image]

Comment: I am having trouble following what you are saying, can you post the actually commands you are trying to run? and your PATH?

Comment: Also is your Perl interpreter definitely at `/usr/bin/perl`?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen the perl interpreter is under /use/bin/perl yes.

Comment: That syntax error is not from `perl`. It seems your shebang is being ignored, for some reason. Can you provide a hexdump of the first two lines: `head -n 2 <~/.tools/shuffle.pl | od -t ax1`? This would discover wrong line endings or a BOM before the `#!`.

Comment: I believe *less* shows control characters by default also.

Comment: That hexdump tells us that the shebang is not in the first line. Can you assert that? Does it work when you delete everything before the `#!`? The shebang *has* to be at the very beginning of the file in order to work.

Comment: @amon After I delete all character before #! it finally work ... thanks

Comment: @amon But I don't put #! in the beginning of file before , but it still works ... anyway problem solved thanks .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shebang is used to tell which interpreter should be used for this script. For this to work, the magic number `#!` has to appear at the immediate beginning of the file. Otherwise, the default interpreter is used.

In this case, the shebang was preceded by a few empty lines. They have to be removed.

The shebang is not parsed when an explicit interpreter is used to execute the file, E.g. in `$ perl script.pl`.
It is only  important when launched as executable: `./script.pl`. In that case, the kernel is left to figure out what to do with it: Load into memory as compiled program? Launch an interpreter? Which one? Magic numbers like `#!` resolve this.

In general, if the shebang doesn't work, the following possible errors can be checked:

- An UTF byte order mark precedes the `#!`.
  *Diagnosis:* A hexdump shows `FE FF` at the beginning.
  *Solution:* configure your editor to store files without a BOM
- The script is encoded in such a way that the beginning does not decode to `#!` as ASCII.
  *Diagnosis:* The file does not begin with `#!` when opened as ASCII or does not begin with `23 21` in a hexdump. Or your editor shows UTF-16 or UTF-32 as the encoding.
  *Solution:* Store the script in ASCII-compatible encoding. UTF-8 is an especially good choice.
- Non-native line endings can be confused to be part of the executable name. E.g. with windows line endings, the shebang in

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/perl
  print 1;
  ```

  could be taken as the interpreter name `"/usr/bin/perl\r"`. Many filesystems allow line endings inside filenames.
  *Diagnosis:* A hexdump shows something other than a space (`20`) or newline (`0A`) after the executable name.
  *Solution:* Convert line endings to Unix.

Answer (score 0):

A few general tips:

- You should have -w on the shebang line to catch warnings.
- You should probably `use strict;` also.
- Don't put double quotes around "$ARGV[0]" and "$ARGV[1]" because they serve no purpose.
- Use "do or die" syntax on the file opens, e.g.:

  open (File, "<", $ARGV[0]) || die "File open error: $!";

Do those things and I am pretty sure the solution will appear rapidly.

Comment: and NEVER use Barewords for Filehandle as well!! use `open my $fh, '>', '...';` instead of `open FH, '>', '...';`